# Generating Base 64 IDs

Tags: c#, database-design, youtube, base64

This question will be mainly opinion based I think, however, I have created my own Base64 ID generator for the visible ID column of my database tables for security reasons, (I saw a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8) as to why YouTube do it and it made sense although I see other ways of security that probably aren't as problematic). It handles the **HIGHLY** unlikely event that a duplicate may arise, however, I am curious to know if this is used as a standard for say, YouTube's video IDs.

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ids = new HashSet<string>();
        var count = 0; // for testing only
        while (count < 8)
        {
            ids.Add(Base64Id.GenerateId(ids));
            Console.ReadLine();
            count++; // for testing only
        }
    }
}
```

**Base64Id.cs**

```
public static class Base64Id
{
    private static int IdSize = 1; // Should be 11
    private static readonly string[] AllowedChars = {
        "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"//,
        //"8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",
        //"g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
        //"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
        //"w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D",
        //"E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
        //"M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
        //"U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "-", "_"
    };

    private static Random _random = new Random();

    /// <summary>
    /// To generate a Base64 ID and check to make sure the ID is not already in use.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="usedIds">List of IDs already in use from the Database or other source.</param>
    /// <returns>New Base64 ID</returns>
    public static string GenerateId(HashSet<string> usedIds)
    {
        var autoGenId = "";

        do
        {
            autoGenId = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < IdSize; i++)
                autoGenId += GetRandomChar();
#if DEBUG
            _DEBUG_(usedIds.Count() + 1, autoGenId);
#endif
        }
        while (IsTaken(autoGenId, usedIds));

        return autoGenId;
    }

    private static string GetRandomChar()
    {
        var i = _random.Next(0, AllowedChars.Length);
        return AllowedChars[i];
    }

    private static bool IsTaken(string id, HashSet<string> usedIds)
    {
        var check = usedIds.Any(i => id.Contains(i));
        if (check)
            return true;


        return false;
    }

    private static void _DEBUG_(int count, string id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}:\t{1}", count, id));
    }
}
```

I believe that this will work like a charm for my purposes and without any issues, as it does during testing. **However**, once I narrow it down to 8 chars and with an ID size of length 1, it kicks up serious errors due to the constant looping after only 6 of the 8 expected outputs have happened.

I understand this is from a random number being hit each time and the less that there are to choose from, the more likely the loop must occur.

I know ways to remedy this, however on the scale I plan for, it is crazy to think of, such as having an array/list of every possibility and removing the selected ID.

This is my question;

> 1. Do the likes of Youtube know of this problem, and just don't care due to the size of possible IDs.
> 2. They just have much greater thought put into the class.
> 3. They do not care about the processing cost for such high numbers and handle every small detail.
> 4. Or do they use Base64Encode in there code instead of auto-generating it.

I would like to know your opinions and suggestions on how to improve the code or if it even matters which such huge numbers. I have answered with what I think could be possible ways to improve it.

**UPDATE**

I left two consoles run over the weekend, one using `List` and the other using `HashSet`, and the difference between the processed records is on a whole other level. So I have changed the above code to have `HashSet` instead of `List`, and set the code up to run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for the amount of possible IDs, it is not worth the serious amount of processing it would require to make sure that the ID is unique the further it goes to the end of the list as there are **73,786,976,294,838,206,464** possibilities.

Say for ten possible IDs 1 -> 10, if 2 have been selected already, then the next time, it has a 20% chance of be duplicated, and if 8 have been selected it will be 80% chance, **each time**. Using probability, this will stack and lower your chances of getting a unique ID to appear.

This is quiet bad once the numbers are low, it took 14539279 iterations the first time and 662984 iterations the second time to get all 8 unique IDs to appear. With bigger numbers I know it will take longer to get to this breaking point, but it will be much worse.

I think that this could be split up into a binary tree once the numbers get bigger as to make the most of it, once each block of say a couple 100k or million reaches 50% or 60% usage, forget the rest and move onto the next range.

I think this could be a good way to try and speed up processing a unique ID into the later stages of the possible list.